# Jenkins Email Notification to Build-Requestor (URL-Trigger)

Tags: jenkins, email-notifications

i want to sent a email to the build-requestor after the jenkins build is finished. I configured under "post-build Actions" a "editable email notification", as trigger i defined "always send to requestor". But this only works if i start the build over the "build now" button in jenkins.

I start the build over an url-trigger in JavaScript, after the trigger is started i only need to enter my credentials and the build starts, but i dont get any notification.

Build-Log by URL-trigger usage:

*Email was triggered for: Always*

*Sending email for trigger: Always*

*An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignor*ed.

Is there any possibility to get the email to the requestor? Maybe another plugin or post-script?

Answer (score 0):

In the Editable Email Notification, you can see what the requestor option does:

"Sends email to the user who initiated the build."

The problem is a build triggered remotely will not have a user associated with the build, instead it will say "Started by remote host". Since this Jenkins job isn't technically started by a user, it has no one to email.

You can try going around this by passing in a parameter that will have your recipient list.